# Akka Cluster - MemberUp message from dead letters not delivered

Tags: java, akka, cluster-computing

I'm starting learning Akka and its Cluster extension using Java libraries (both v. 2.3.9). I'm trying to configure a cluster in which an action should be performed when at least 3 members are up. I used the registerOnMemberUp method of the Cluster object and this seems to work, but there are some random logs at the beginning (they are always < 3 lines for each node, I think this is someway related to the configuration) that warn about some messages of MemberUp type cannot be delivered from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] to some other Actors.

```
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.050] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.268] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700]
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.268] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700]
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.268] [main] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Starting up...
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.346] [main] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.346] [main] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Started up successfully
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.362] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.362] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[04/12/2015 15:08:31.362] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] is JOINING, roles [backend]
[04/12/2015 15:08:38.618] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:3253] is JOINING, roles [backend]
[04/12/2015 15:08:49.469] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:7566] is JOINING, roles [backend]
[04/12/2015 15:08:50.374] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] to [Up]
[04/12/2015 15:08:50.374] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:3253] to [Up]
[04/12/2015 15:08:50.374] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2700] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:7566] to [Up]
[04/12/2015 15:08:50.374] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/$a] Message [akka.cluster.ClusterEvent$MemberUp] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/$a#-1847673604] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[04/12/2015 15:08:50.374] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/$a] Message [akka.cluster.ClusterEvent$MemberUp] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/$a#-1847673604] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

In this example, I started 3 nodes, the first one with a fixed port (it's hardcoded as the only seed node), the others with a manually specified port. Following there is the configuration and the code:

**application.conf**

```
akka {    
  actor.provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"    
  remote.netty.tcp.port=0
  remote.netty.tcp.hostname=127.0.0.1    
  cluster {
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
    min-nr-of-members = 3
    roles = ["backend"]
    role {
        backend {
            min-nr-of-members = 3
        }
    }    
  }    
  extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]   
}
```

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

    private final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 2700;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().start();
    }

    private void start() throws Exception {

        int port = getPort();
        Config conf = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.cluster.seed-nodes=[\"akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:" + DEFAULT_PORT + "\"]")
                .withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=" + port))
                .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());

        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem", conf);
        ClusterMonitorFrame frame = new ClusterMonitorFrame(system, port);

        /* Create and display the form */
        //system.actorOf(Props.create(ClusterStatusWatcher.class, frame), "clusterStatusWatcherActor");
        //ActorRef clusterMember = system.actorOf(Props.create(ClusterMember.class), "clusterMemberActor");

        Runnable r = () -> {};

        Cluster.get(system).registerOnMemberUp(r);

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
    }

    private int getPort() throws HeadlessException, SocketException, NumberFormatException {
        int port;
        if (Utils.available(DEFAULT_PORT)) {
            port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        } else {
            String portStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert the listening port");
            port = Integer.parseInt(portStr);
            if (!Utils.available(port)) {
                throw new SocketException();
            }
        }
        return port;
    }

}
```

I have disabled other actors creation and form displaying, only the cluster startup code is present and the call to registerOnMemberUp with an empty Runnable block. The issue remains. Can be these dead letters captured in some way? Do I have to concern about them?

Comment: It's not uncommon for akka to use deadletter for diagnostic/metrics messages (see for example spray's bind mechanic). If everything else works, ignore it.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you about this, but it seems a bit strange that for a basic scenario like the one I set up there is no handling of these MemberUp messages, and the Dead Letters actor is forced to discard them. Furthermore, this behaviour isn't documented at all, and a beginner (like me) could think there is some wrong configuration or actor misuse. I hope someone among the project owners could intervene and give a final answer about this issue.

Comment: MemberUp is a message as others. As you can read here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/cluster-usage.html you need to handle it yourself if you care about it, or it goes to deadletters :) (ctrl+f on the page for the relevant sections)

Comment: I totally agree with you, and I have read that document (the starting point of my test was the example about the registerOnMemberUp event, indeed). But, I tried also to catch MemberUp message within a custom actor (the one that is created in the comment block), and actually the message is correctly delivered to that actor, but the log still complain about that "akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/$a#-1847673604" actor, that I don't know at all, and cannot manage its lifecycle.

Comment: Try sending an Identify message to that actorref (use system.actorselection) and maybe that helps you gather more info on who that actor is.

Comment: Hi! It'd be really useful if you could share this reproducer as a runnable (github?) project. In general these dead letters are typically not something to worry about, but I agree it'd be interesting to see where these came from.

Comment: OK I was intrigued so I put the reproducer code in an sbt project myself, https://github.com/raboof/akka-cluster-memberup-message-from-dead-letters-not-delivered - but there I don't see the dead letters you get. Perhaps it's caused by something you didn't share yet?

Comment: You are commenting an issue of 2 years ago... maybe things are changed in the meanwhile? :)

Comment: Well, I did try with akka 2.3.9... (the reason for taking a look is that someone on the akka-user mailinglist reported having the same problem)